# How to update the amount value when the user add data and store it to list view flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, google-cloud-platform

Hi guys I'm new in flutter and need your help. In this case, i'm able to add the budget and retrieve it to list view. but now I'm trying show only 1 list for each category but count for the amount? so if the user add the new budget, the amount will be count and updated to the list view (with the same currency). Anyone can help me how to list the the same category but with updated amount if the user add the budget in the budget code? Please help. Thank you. For the database, I'm using Firestore in the firebase

[image: Here is the firebase]

[image: Like this I want to add the food category into 1 list which is IDR 160.]

choose budget category

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/localization/localization_constants.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/page/detail.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/theme/colors.dart';

class BudgetSettings extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BudgetSettingsState createState() => _BudgetSettingsState();
}

class _BudgetSettingsState extends State<BudgetSettings> {
  List<Container> categorylist = new List();

  var character=[
    {"name":"Food", "image":"food.png"},
    {"name":"Social-Life", "image":"travel.png"},
    {"name":"Transportation", "image":"transportation.png"},
    {"name":"Beauty", "image":"makeup.png"},
    {"name":"Household", "image":"household.png"},
    {"name":"Education", "image":"education.png"},
    {"name":"Health", "image":"health.png"},
    {"name":"Gift", "image":"gift.png"},
    {"name":"Other", "image":"other.png"},
  ];
  _makelist() async {
    for (var i = 0; i < character.length; i++) {
      final newcharacter = character[i];
      final String image = newcharacter["image"];
      categorylist.add(
        new Container(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: new Card( child:
              SingleChildScrollView(
                child: new Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Hero(
                          tag: newcharacter['name'], 
                          child: new Material(
                            child: new InkWell(
                              onTap: ()=> Navigator.of(context).push(new MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (BuildContext context)=> new Detail(name: newcharacter['name'], image: image,),

                              )),
                                child:
                                  new Image.asset("assets/$image", fit: BoxFit.contain,),
                                )
                              ),
                              ),

                        //new Image.asset('assets/$image', fit: BoxFit.cover,),
                        new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),),
                        new Text(newcharacter['name'], style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),),
                      ],
                    ),
              ),
            ),
            ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _makelist();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: primary,
        title: Text(getTranslated((context), "budget_settings"),

      ),),

      body: new GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: categorylist,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Add budget code

```
import 'package:dropdownfield/dropdownfield.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/localization/localization_constants.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/page/account.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/page/budgetsettings.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/theme/colors.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class Detail extends StatefulWidget {


  Detail({this.name, this.image});
  final String name;
  final String image;

  @override
  _DetailState createState() => _DetailState();
}

class _DetailState extends State<Detail> {
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(getTranslated((context), "budget_settings"),),
        elevation: 0,
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        backgroundColor: primary,
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.pop(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Account()));
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios,
            size: 20,
            color: Colors.black,),
        ),
      ),
      body: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
              height: 250.0,
              child:
              new Hero(tag: widget.name,
                  child: new Material(
                      child: new InkWell(
                        child: new Image.asset("assets/${widget.image}", fit: BoxFit.contain,),
                      )
                  ))
          ),
          new Name(name: widget.name,),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Name extends StatefulWidget {
  Name({this.name});
  final String name;

  @override
  _NameState createState() => _NameState();
}

class _NameState extends State<Name> {
  @override
  String selectCurrency;

  final currencySelected = TextEditingController();
  var _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();


  List <String> currencycategories = [
    "IDR",
    "MYR",
    "USD",
    "CNY"
  ];
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final amount = TextEditingController();
    FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    CollectionReference collect= firestore.collection("Budget");

    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final User user =_auth.currentUser;
    final uid = user.uid;

    return Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                          child: Text(
                            widget.name,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: new TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 25.0,
                              color: primary,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: <Widget> [
                            new Expanded(child: new DropDownField(
                              controller: currencySelected,
                              labelText: getTranslated((context), "currency_hint"),
                              enabled: true,
                              itemsVisibleInDropdown: 4,
                              items: currencycategories,
                              onValueChanged: (dynamic value) {
                                selectCurrency = value;
                              },
                              value: selectCurrency,
                              required: false,
                            ),
                              flex: 2,
                            ),
                            new SizedBox(
                              width: 10.0,
                            ),
                            new Expanded(child: TextFormField(
                              validator: (input) {
                                if (input.isEmpty) return 'Please fill up the text fields';
                              },
                              controller: amount,
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                                labelText: getTranslated((context), "budget_enter"),
                                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(

                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: secondary),
                                ),
                                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: secondary),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                              flex: 2,
                            )],
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                          child: ElevatedButton(

                            onPressed: () async {
                              final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth
                                  .instance;
                              final User user = _auth.currentUser;
                              final uid = user.uid;

                              if(!_formKey.currentState.validate()){
                                return;
                              }
                              _formKey.currentState.save();

                              collect.add({
                                'name': this.widget.name,
                                'currency': selectCurrency,
                                'amount': amount.text,
                              });
                              amount.text = "";
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },
                            child: Text(getTranslated((context), "save_button").toUpperCase(), style: TextStyle (
                              fontSize: 14,
                            )),
                            style: ButtonStyle(
                              padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(EdgeInsets.all(20.0)),
                              foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),
                              backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.pink),
                              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                    side: BorderSide(color: secondary)
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),

                          ),
                        )
                      ],


                    ),
                  )

              )
            ],
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Retrieve it to list view code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/localization/localization_constants.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/page/transaction.dart';
import 'package:monger_app/theme/colors.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import './transaction.dart' as expense;
import './transaction.dart' as income;

class TransactionMonthly extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TransactionMonthlyState createState() => _TransactionMonthlyState();
}

class _TransactionMonthlyState extends State<TransactionMonthly> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  TabController controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = new TabController(vsync: this, length: 2);
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(getTranslated(context, 'budget_title'),),
        elevation: 0,
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        backgroundColor: primary,
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.pop(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Transactions()));
          },
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios,
            size: 20,
            color: Colors.black,),
        ),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Budget').snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return ListView(
                children: snapshot.data.docs.map((document) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Row(children: [
                          SizedBox(width: 10,),
                          Text(document.get('name'),style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,
                              color: primary,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
                          ),),
                        ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10,),
                        Row(children: [
                          SizedBox(width: 10,),
                          Text(document.get('currency'),style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,
                              color: primary,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
                          ),),
                          SizedBox(width: 10,),
                          Text(document.get('amount'),style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,
                              color: primary,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
                          ),),
                        ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 8,),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: [
                            GestureDetector(
                              onTap: (){
                                Widget cancelButton = FlatButton(child: Text("Cancel"),
                                  onPressed: (){
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                  },
                                );
                                Widget deleteButton = FlatButton(child: Text("Delete"),
                                  onPressed: (){
                                    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Budget').doc(document.id).delete();
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                  },
                                );
                                showDialog(
                                  context: context,
                                  builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                                    title: Text('Delete Budget'),
                                    content: Text('Are you sure want to delete it?'),
                                    actions: [
                                      cancelButton,
                                      deleteButton,
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                );
                                //_showDeleteDialog();
                                //_showDeleteDialog(document: document);
                              },
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Icon(Icons.delete_forever_outlined,
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(width: 6,),
                                  Text('Delete', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,
                                      color: Colors.red,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
                                  ), ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        )
                      ],)
                  );
                }).toList(),
              );
            }
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is a sort of group by name so that you show the food category with 160 in your example instead of two times the same category (Correct me if i am wrong). What i suggest is to first create a class named `Budget` with your three attributes `name, currency and amount`. When you receive your data in `TransactionMonthly Streambuilder` you need to group your snapshot data by name. Once you done that you create a list of budgets `List<Budget> budgets` so that you add the sum of amount per name of budgets.

Here is a sample code that you can use, you can simply copy paste it and try on DartPad by yourself:

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

//DATA coming from your Firebase collection

Map<String, dynamic> data1 = {
  'name':"Food",
  'currency': "IDR",
  'amount': 100,
};


Map<String, dynamic> data2 = {
  'name':"Food",
  'currency': "IDR",
  'amount': 60,
};

Map<String, dynamic> data3 = {
  'name':"Beauty",
  'currency': "USD",
  'amount': 120,
};

//Your Budget class

class Budget{
  String currency;
  String name;
  int amount;
  
  @override
  String toString(){
     return "Budget: {currency: $currency, name: $name, amount: $amount}";
  }
  
  Budget({required this.currency, required this.name, required this.amount});
}



void main(){

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot = [data1, data2, data3]; 
  List<Budget> budgets = [];

//you group your budgets by name so you will have: {'Food': [data1, data2], 'Beauty':[data3]}

final groupByName = groupBy(snapshot, (Map<String, dynamic> doc)=>doc['name']);
  
  print(groupByName);
  
  int totalAmount = 0;
  String currency = "";
  
  groupByName.forEach((name, value){
    //because we grouped by name every value will have same currency
    currency = value[0]['currency'];

    //Here we calculate the sum of all Food 
    totalAmount = value.map((e)=>e['amount']).reduce((v, e)=> v+e);
    budgets.add(Budget(currency: currency, amount: totalAmount, name: name));
  });
  
 //budgets is your final list to use in your listView
print(budgets);
}
```

Comment: hi for the data that come from firebase collection I make it based on the user input not using raw data in the add budget code. is it still use the same method?

Comment: I mean if I add the budget for "Food" and it stored to the firebase and show in the list view and if I add the budget for "Food" again, in the list view, it should show the sum of the total budget for food. But if the new category "Life Style" (for example) is added, it still show in the list view based on user input

Comment: Yes because you are using a Streambuilder. You need to do this group by everytime you receive a new value so just after your (snapshot.hasData) you do this groupBy and use it in your ListView. Everytime you will add Budget document it will work.

Comment: can you fix my code? I'm not really understand about that

Comment: You also need to pay attention to delete because everything is grouped by name you need then to delete every document with the same name in you budget collection.

Comment: where should i include the code that you provide is it in the TransactionMonthly ?

Comment: or you can help me to fix the code since it is already works for retrieve the data to list view  but I don't understand how to calculate the total amount and show it to the listview

Comment: List<Budget> budgets = [];
final groupByName = groupBy(snapshot, (Map<String, dynamic> doc)=>doc['name']);
  
  int totalAmount = 0;
  String currency = "";
  
  groupByName.forEach((name, value){
    currency = value[0]['currency'];
    totalAmount = value.map((e)=>e['amount']).reduce((v, e)=> v+e);
    budgets.add(Budget(currency: currency, amount: totalAmount, name: name));
  });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234435/discussion-between-arton-hoxha-and-new-user).